# SQL record matching

Tags: sql, postgresql

I get 2 records from queries.
First record is:

```
1|1
2|2
3|3
```

Second is

```
1|4
2|5
3|6
```

How to return table a+b?

```
1|5
2|7
3|9
```

Comment: This is pretty much a basic join.  Have you tried anything?

Comment: I understand join as 1|1|4, 2|2|5, 3|3|6, but not summing. Mb some code?

Comment: @Virvill . . . It is not particularly complicated:  `first.col2 + second.col2`

Comment: `SELECT a.col1+b.col1 FROM a NATURAL JOIN b`?

Comment: @Virvil . . . Don't use `natural join`.  It is a bug waiting to happen.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very basic join between the two tables:

```
select t1.id, t1.col1 + t2.col2
from t1 
  join t2 on t1.id = t2.id
```